# How to make the touchstart and touchend and touchover work with mouse events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a basic mobile ready audio player using HTML5 audio tags.

so far I can make things work properly in the browser and with the mouse events.

But when I try the same functions in a touch ready device, everything is so clunky (not smooth) and the touch events do not work at all.

This is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/nkhy0sxf/

I tried somethign like this:

```
$pie.on("mousedown touchstart", function (eDown) {

        if($(eDown.target).is("#pie")) {
            var seeking = true;

            var percent = computeProgress(eDown);
            player.currentTime = percent * player.duration / 100;

            $(this).on("mouseup mouseout touchend", function () {

                seeking = false;
            });

            $(this).on("mousemove touchmove", function (eMove) {
                if(seeking == true) {
                    var percent = computeProgress(eMove);
                    player.currentTime = percent * player.duration / 100;
                }
            });
```

But the issue that i mentioned above persists on touch ready devices.

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You must take a look to [hammer.js](https://hammerjs.github.io/).